# how to show dialog after ten button click

Tags: android, eclipse

```
counter initialize with zero value
    int counter=0;
    bnt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
    bnt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
     bnt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
    bnt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
     bnt5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
    bnt6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
     bnt7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
     bnt8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
     bnt9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });
     bnt10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                    counter +=1;


                 }
             });

    if(counter==10){
          Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
           d.show();
      }
```

But not show dialog anybody help me. I want to get dialog after ten buttons click
or any other method please help me how to show dialog after ten buttons clicks
 thanks in Advance

Comment: you want to check 10 hits on same button or different buttons?

Comment: @Ghulam Jilani you have to respond the comments, then only we know the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to test if counter equals 10 inside every OnClickListener of your buttons

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
    int counter=0;
    bnt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;
            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }

        }
    });
    bnt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
    bnt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
    bnt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
    bnt5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
    bnt6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
    bnt7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
    bnt8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
    bnt9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
    bnt10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            counter +=1;

            if(counter >= 10){
                Dialog d =new Dialog(this);
                d.show();
            }
        }
    });
```